# PySpark DataFrame showing different results when using .select()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Why is `.select()` showing/parsing values differently to I don't use it?

I have this CSV:

```
CompanyName, CompanyNumber,RegAddress.CareOf,RegAddress.POBox,RegAddress.AddressLine1, RegAddress.AddressLine2,RegAddress.PostTown,RegAddress.County,RegAddress.Country,RegAddress.PostCode,CompanyCategory,CompanyStatus,CountryOfOrigin,DissolutionDate,IncorporationDate,Accounts.AccountRefDay,Accounts.AccountRefMonth,Accounts.NextDueDate,Accounts.LastMadeUpDate,Accounts.AccountCategory,Returns.NextDueDate,Returns.LastMadeUpDate,Mortgages.NumMortCharges,Mortgages.NumMortOutstanding,Mortgages.NumMortPartSatisfied,Mortgages.NumMortSatisfied,SICCode.SicText_1,SICCode.SicText_2,SICCode.SicText_3,SICCode.SicText_4,LimitedPartnerships.NumGenPartners,LimitedPartnerships.NumLimPartners,URI,PreviousName_1.CONDATE, PreviousName_1.CompanyName, PreviousName_2.CONDATE, PreviousName_2.CompanyName,PreviousName_3.CONDATE, PreviousName_3.CompanyName,PreviousName_4.CONDATE, PreviousName_4.CompanyName,PreviousName_5.CONDATE, PreviousName_5.CompanyName,PreviousName_6.CONDATE, PreviousName_6.CompanyName,PreviousName_7.CONDATE, PreviousName_7.CompanyName,PreviousName_8.CONDATE, PreviousName_8.CompanyName,PreviousName_9.CONDATE, PreviousName_9.CompanyName,PreviousName_10.CONDATE, PreviousName_10.CompanyName,ConfStmtNextDueDate, ConfStmtLastMadeUpDate
"ATS CAR RENTALS LIMITED","10795807","","",", 1ST FLOOR ,WESTHILL HOUSE 2B DEVONSHIRE ROAD","ACCOUNTING FREEDOM","BEXLEYHEATH","","ENGLAND","DA6 8DS","Private Limited Company","Active","United Kingdom","","31/05/2017","31","5","28/02/2023","31/05/2021","TOTAL EXEMPTION FULL","28/06/2018","","0","0","0","0","49390 - Other passenger land transport","","","","0","0","http://business.data.gov.uk/id/company/10795807","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","12/06/2023","29/05/2022"
"ATS CARE LIMITED","10393661","","","UNIT 5 CO-OP BUILDINGS HIGH STREET","ABERSYCHAN","PONTYPOOL","TORFAEN","WALES","NP4 7AE","Private Limited Company","Active","United Kingdom","","26/09/2016","30","9","30/06/2023","30/09/2021","UNAUDITED ABRIDGED","24/10/2017","","0","0","0","0","87900 - Other residential care activities n.e.c.","","","","0","0","http://business.data.gov.uk/id/company/10393661","17/05/2018","ATS SUPPORT LIMITED","22/12/2017","ATS CARE LIMITED","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","09/10/2022","25/09/2021"
```

I'm reading the csv like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
_file = "/path/dir/BasicCompanyDataAsOneFile-2022-08-01.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(_file, header=True, quote='"', escape="\"")
```

Focusing on the `CompanyCategory` column, we should see `Private Limited Company` for both lines. But this is what I get instead when using `select()`:

```py
df.select("CompanyCategory").show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------+
|CompanyCategory        |
+-----------------------+
|DA6 8DS                |
|Private Limited Company|
+-----------------------+
```

```py
df.select("CompanyCategory").collect()

[Row(CompanyCategory='DA6 8DS'),
 Row(CompanyCategory='Private Limited Company')]
```

vs when not using `select()`:

```py
from pprint import pprint
for row in df.collect():
    pprint(row.asDict())
```

```
{' CompanyNumber': '10795807',
 ...
 'CompanyCategory': 'Private Limited Company',
 'CompanyName': 'ATS CAR RENTALS LIMITED',
 ...}
{' CompanyNumber': '10393661',
...
 'CompanyCategory': 'Private Limited Company',
 'CompanyName': 'ATS CARE LIMITED',
...}
```

Using `asDict()` for readability.

SQL doing the same thing:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("companies")
spark.sql('select CompanyCategory from companies').show()

+--------------------+
|     CompanyCategory|
+--------------------+
|Private Limited C...|
|             DA6 8DS|
+--------------------+
```

As you can see when not using `select()` the `CompanyCategory` values are showing correctly. Why is this happening? What can I do to avoid this?

Context: I'm trying to creating dimension tables which is why I'm selecting a single column. The next phase is to drop duplicates, filter, sort, etc.

### Edit:

Here are two example values in the actual CSV that are throwing things off:

- CompanyName of `""" BORA "" 2 LTD"`
- 1st line address of `", 1ST FLOOR ,WESTHILL HOUSE 2B DEVONSHIRE ROAD"`

Note:

- These values from two separate distinct lines in the CSV.
- These values are copy and pasted from the CSV opened in text editor like Notepad or VSCode).

Tried and failed:

1. `df = spark.read.csv(_file, header=True)` - completely picks up incorrect column.
2. `df = spark.read.csv(_file, header=True, escape='\"')` - exact same thing described in original question above. So same results.
3. `df = spark.read.csv(_file, header=True, escape='""')` - since the CSV **escapes** quotes using two double quotes, then I guess using two double quotes as escape param would do the trick? But getting following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o276.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: escape cannot be more than one character
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading the csv, the [parameters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) `quote` and `escape` are set to the same value (`'"'=="\""` returns `True` in Python).

I would guess that configuring both parameters in this way will somehow disturb the parser that Spark uses to separate the single fields. After removing the `escape` parameter you can process the remaining `"` with [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.csv(<filename>, header=True, quote='"')
cols = [F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(
    F.regexp_replace("`" + col + "`", '^"', ''), 
    '"$', ''), '""', '"').alias(col) for col in df.columns]
df.select(cols).show(truncate=False)
```

Probably there is a smart regexp that can combine all three replace operations into one...

Comment: Makes sense, although still having trouble with my original CSV. I've added two examples to my question that I think is causing the problem, just don't know how to fix that? It's weird because `pandas` has no trouble reading the CSV, and a `COPY` to a PostgreSQL table has no problem parsing and selecting from but Spark requires additional config? Note: the original data is found here: http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue when reading a single column from CSV file vs. when reading all the columns:

```
df = spark.read.csv('companies-house.csv', header=True, quote='"', escape="\"")
df.show()  # correct output (all columns loaded)
df.toPandas()  # same as pd.read_csv()

df.select('CompanyCategory').show()  # wrong output (trying to load a single column)

df.cache()  # all columns will be loaded and used in any subsequent call
df.select('CompanyCategory').show()  # correct output
```

The first `select()` performs a different (optimized) read than the second, so one possible workaround would be to `cache()` the data immediately. This will however load all the columns, not just one (although `pandas` and `COPY` do the same).

The problematic part of the CSV is the `RegAddress.POBox` column where empty value is saved as `",` instead of `"",`. You can check this by incrementally loading more columns:

```
df.unpersist()  # undo cache() operation (for testing purposes only)
df.select(*[f"`{c}`" for c in df.columns[:3]], 'CompanyCategory').show()  # wrong
df.select(*[f"`{c}`" for c in df.columns[:4]], 'CompanyCategory').show()  # OK
```